# is that possible to use vue 3 typscript component in vue 2 js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I currently have project VueJS 2, and that project gonna whole revamp, but per phase, so it might take time to revamp and wait to finish , so I have an idea to create Vue 3 with Typescript and then use that component into VueJS 2 ? is that possible ? should I make Vue 3 to be mixin so I can use it on VueJS 2 ?

let say phase 1 , I revamp for Homepage only, so I replace the component Homepage with Vue 3 typescript component into that VueJS 2

Comment: No. Compile it separately and make it a sub-app. At this point this isn't much different to Vue-React bridge, only that with Vue 2/3 there's a good match on framework lifecycle.

Comment: You should checkout https://stenciljs.com/, it's framework agnostic.

Comment: @EstusFlask is that means not good to have 2 apps with different versions??

Comment: @RosdiKasim hmmm i need to see it, i never heard that before but need time to learn it again :(

Comment: 2 apps will consume more traffic because they will have different dependency sets. It may acceptable if it's temporary.

Comment: it might just be temporary till finish whole the revamp, because i will revamp the website to new looks and new components, but we revamp it per phase , so don't know how long because i do this by myself :( @EstusFlask, what is the suggestion for this ?

Comment: Create an instance of compiled Vue 3 app (`new Vue3(...).mount(v3Container)`) inside Vue 2 component and set V3 instance data when you need to update it, when V2 props are updated or else. Can't provide a ready to use code.

Comment: i am planning to use Vue 3 cli, so is that mean I should build it ? and then use it in vue 2 ? because for phase 1, i only revamp the Homepage only and i plan to redirect routes to things to vue 2 also, so for "/" root router is vue 3 and other routes vue 2 @EstusFlask

Comment: Yes, it needs to be built, so it's uses its own `vue` dependency, etc with no conflicts with V2 app. You likely need to keep V2 router to the end, with routes being V2 wrappers around respective V3 comps, at this this would be my strategy for migration. You'll possibly need to shim some things in Vue 3, e.g. there's no router-link because a router belongs to parent app so it needs to be recreated

Comment: Depending on your case, it could be easier to incorporate TS into V2 app and gradually rewrite things with composition API, with 2 to 3 migration guidelines in mind.

Comment: yes, thanks for your suggestion :) i will try the best @EstusFlask